# Как вернуть медиагруппу (2 фото + текст) и нужную клавиатуру?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Нигде не могу найти нужную функцию, есть `answer_photo`, но там только 1 фото, а `send_media_group` не дает установить клавиатуру.

Answer (score 0):

К медиагруппе нельзя привязывать клавиатуру. Подробнее тут - https://docs.aiogram.dev/uk-ua/latest/api/methods/send_media_group.html

В качестве альтернативы можно просто отправлять два сообщения - с медиагруппой и текстом отдельно.